# Is there anyway to help a pinned down teammate?

Tags: the-outlast-trials

A reoccurring theme in the game is you will often get jumped by a hostile who will pin you to the ground and pummel you until you mash a button enough times to get them off of you. If this happens to my friend, all I've been able to do is watch it seems. Walking up to my pinned down ally doesn't seem to give me any options to help get the enemy off my friend.

Is there anything I can do to help get the enemy off my friend?

Comment: Could you throw a brick to them? I remember that I could in Beta, but I'm not sure if it's doable in released version

Comment: @Skye-AT I haven't tried this yet still, primarily because I've found I haven't had a brick with me whenever my friend gets jumped, but it sounds very promising.

Comment: I've watched my video archive of the game and found out that I've threw a bottle to the big-guy that's walking around police station and it stunned them, so maybe it's worth a try as well. I'd say if the bottles can do the thing then bricks should too, but yeah, not sure. I don't know if it's worth a use if you can save teammates by using skills, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ["Update #2"](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/1304930/view/3672169366909882757?l=english), the perks have been renamed, and you can help teammates without any perks, but not having any perks have a caveat:

> - "KICK TO HELP" is now "HARD KICK":
>
>   - Players Can now help teammates grasped by enemies without needing to acquire an upgrade
>   - However, helping teammates now exhausts the player.
>   - Purchasing "HARD KICK" prescription greatly reduces the stamina cost of helping teammates
> - "LIFE SAVER” is now “STAY OF EXECUTION”:
>
>   - Players can now save teammates being executed by enemies without needing to acquire an upgrade.
>   - Saving teammates now exhausts the player.
>   - Purchasing this prescription greatly reduces the stamina cost when performing this action.
> - Players who acquired the previous prescriptions will automatically receive the newer version and it will be equipped. New players will have to acquire them as usual.

---

**Original Answer**:

There are some perks you can purchase at the pharmacy which unlocks at level 3 that can help that I've only discovered now (having reached the level to use the pharmacy). But to reiterate from a source, [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-outlast-trials/Upgrades) states:

- **Kick to Help**:

> You can kick an enemy that has grabbed your friend.

- **Life Saver**:

> You can kick enemies to stop them from executing your friends.

*Kick to Help* is exactly the kind of ability that should work, but *Life Saver* does have a similar (though probably less common) use.

Comment: You mean [this post](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/1304930/view/3672169366909882757?l=english)?

Comment: @Skye-AT yes - i couldn't find a dedicated link to it! I'll edit my answer

Comment: You can find the link by going all the way down of the patch notes, there should be "Share" button, it opens a dialog and lets you copy the link :)